# The same function with different arguments called many times consecutively using dplyr pipes?

Tags: r, dplyr

What I would like to achieve in general would be that I could do the following:

```
df %>%
    exampleFunction(1) %>%
    exampleFunction(2) %>%
    exampleFunction(3) %>%
    ...
    exampleFunction(n)
```

And the exampleFunction would be something like:

```
exampleFunction <- function(data, value) {
    #something is done here with the data and value...
    #...and then a new data is returned
}
```

So how this could be achieved?

Of course, I can always use:

```
eval(parse(text="(some dynamically generated code as string)")
```

...but I prefer not to. :)

Comment: It looks like you’re searching for `Reduce()` (or `rlang::reduce()`).

Comment: Sometimes writing a `for` loop is the simplest and clearest solution. So why not do that? `for(i in 1:n){d = examplefunction(d, i)}`

Comment: @Spacedman This depends on the target audience but I’d take `Reduce(examplefunction, seq_len(n), df)` over an opaque `for` loop any day of the week. ;-) — `for` can do literally *anything* so I’d need to read it attentively and be on the lookout for typos. By contrast, the semantics of `Reduce` are well-specified.

Comment: `Reduce(\(x,y) exampleFunction(x, y), 1:n, df)`

Comment: @KonradRudolph i believe you meant `purrr::reduce`. Not sure whether there is reduce in `rlang` though. i might be wrong

Comment: @Onyambu Ah yes, I meant ‘purrr’.

Comment: This is a very general question, in case your "different arguments" are different columns note that there is [dplyr::across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html). If you want to loop over vectors or several columns or both have a look at the [dplyover](https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/) package before reducing several `mutate` calls.

Comment: My problem with `Reduce` is someone not familiar with the function now has to go and read what it does to understand the code, especially since its not clear what's being "reduced" (as in the defn. "made smaller") here (as its a term from FP). But as long as you've been taught fundamentals like for-loops and if-then-else then the for-loop solution has immediate clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a pipeline is (essentially) a shortcut for nested function calls. So your pipeline is roughly the same as:

```
exampleFunction(
  exampleFunction(
    exampleFunction(
      exampleFunction(
        exampleFunction(df, 1),
        2
      ),
      3
    ),
  …,
  n
)
```

This is a generalisation of the code `1 + 2 + 3 + … + n` (with `+` replaced by `exampleFunction`, and where `df` takes the place of the first number). And this kind of pattern is known in functional programming as *reduction*. Core R implements it in the [`Reduce()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) function, and various other packages implement their own variants (e.g. [‘purrr’](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html)).

The usage is as follows:

```
result = Reduce(f, along, init)
```

Which, in your case, is

```
result = Reduce(exampleFunction, seq_len(n), df)
```

Alternatively, you could also explicitly write out the imperative code steps using a `for` loop:

```
result = df
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  result = exampleFunction(result, i)
}
```